# How to get this locale variable into the main script.

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to get this locale variable into the main script. How can I make a global variable from it? This variant does not work, Thanks for the help.

```js
    //Test Script local to global

    (function (exampleCode) {
     "use strict";
 
    var wert = 0.5;
    var name = 'wert';

    Object.assign( exampleCode, {
  
       getValue: function() {
    
         return name;
      
       }
    
     } );
 
    } )( window.exampleCode = window.exampleCode || {} );


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     //main script get 'var wert = 0.5' from Test Script

        var update = function() {
       requestAnimationFrame(update);          
       //var value = wert;     //0.5 
       console.log( exampleCode.getValue() );
       mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 40 ] = params.influence1 = value;   
  }; 
   
  update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need a link to the outer scope of the `getValue` function to get that variable. So, you can store your data in an object and then return `myVars[propName];` in `getValue(propName)` after passing in a name for the property you would like to get. Later it will take its value (0.5) through the closure.

```js
(function (exampleCode) {
    "use strict";
 
    let myVars = {
        wert: 0.5
    };

    Object.assign( exampleCode, {
        getValue: propName => myVars[propName]
    } );
 
    } )( window.exampleCode = window.exampleCode || {} );
    
    let update = function() {         
        let value = exampleCode.getValue('wert');     //0.5 
     console.log( value );
     //mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 40 ] = params.influence1 = value;   
 }; 
   
 update();
```

An alternative is to make `wert` property of `exampleCode` and take its value through `this`:

```js
(function (exampleCode) {
    "use strict";

     Object.assign( exampleCode, {
         getValue: function(propName) { return this[propName]; },
         wert: 0.5
     } );
     
 } )( window.exampleCode = window.exampleCode || {} );
        
 let update = function() {         
     let value = exampleCode.getValue('wert');  
     console.log( value );  
 }; 
       
 update();
```